# Firebase authentication tokens, check if valid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to check if an authentication token is invalid?

> FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeInvalidUserToken

this is shown as a possible error but I can't figure out how to access this error besides when logging in or resetting the password like below.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email, completion: { (error) in
if let err =  error as? NSError {
    if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code){
        if errorCode == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeInvalidUserToken{
            self.alertFunc(title: "Error", message: "invalid token")
        }
    }
} else{
    self.alertFunc(title: "Success", message: "Password reset email has been sent")
}
```

If a user has a few devices logged into the same account, and reset the password on one, then the others will not be able to post to firebase due to their invalid token.  I need the apps on the other devices to be able to recognize the invalid token and then prompt the user for the username and password.

Any help or links would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.getTokenWithCompletion({ (string, err) in
    if err != nil{
        if let err = err as NSError?{
            if let error = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code){
                switch error{
                case .errorCodeInvalidCredential: self.delegate.invalidToken()
                case .errorCodeInvalidUserToken: self.delegate.invalidToken()
                case .errorCodeUserTokenExpired: self.delegate.invalidToken()
                case .errorCodeInvalidCustomToken: self.delegate.invalidToken()
                case .errorCodeCustomTokenMismatch: self.delegate.invalidToken()
                default: print("call default error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```